# Publishing music listen action on Facebook by .NET SDK

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using official Facebook .NET SDK for publish music.listens action by below code.

```
            var result = facebook.Post("me/music.listens", new
            {
                song = new
                {
                    type = "music.song",
                    url = "www.example.com/blabla",
                    title = "Womanizer",
                    image = "www.example.com/blabla",
                    description = "Bu kısma açıklama gelecek",
                    musician = new
                    {
                        type = "profile",
                        title = "Britney Spears",
                        image = "www.example.com/blabla",
                        url = "www.example.com/blabla",
                        description = "Here is great song"
                    }
                }
            })
```

This code publish listen activity  as below format.

> "John listened to Womanizer on MySiteName."

But Pandora.com publish that activity with Artist information as below format.

> "John listened to Womanizer by Britney Spears on Pandora."

This format is what i expected. It also shows tooltip on Artist name by showing Artist photo and with description. For that reason i passed musician information in parameters But Facebook looks ignore that parameter.

How can i represent music listen action as it is Pandora does or what is wrong on passed parameters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used the official .NET SDK to do what you are doing, however I have used direct HTTP POST calls to do this. The Facebook Open Graph requires a "reference object" for the song and musician objects instead of passing the data as parameters. These "reference objects" are just web pages with special meta-data.

In my situation I have a web server that hosts the song and musician meta-data in the Facebook Open Graph formats as described in their documentation. Then I made a me/music.listens post passing the url for the song and the url for the musician.

So instead of passing all the raw data as parameters, you need a web site which hosts all the meta-data.

If you look at the documentation here you will see some examples
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/music.listens

If you go to http://samples.ogp.me/461258627226537 and view the source you can see a sample meta data for the song.

For example here is their php sample (sorry they don't have .NET samples)

```
/* make the API call */
$response = $facebook->api(
    "/me/music.listens",
    "POST",
    array (
        'song' => 'http://samples.ogp.me/461258627226537',
        'musician' => 'http://samples.ogp.me/390580850990722',
    )
);
/* handle the result */
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. It feels strange to provide metadata in that way really. Why we need to produce html document by external api instead of passing parameters directly. So i thought that i can pass all parameters directly. As you can see that facebook accepted parameters that i have sent like image,title,description..etc but i couldn't find a way to pass musician.

Comment: I passed exactly same parameters as it is in example but nothing has changed. May be Pandora using custom action.